# MPMoviePlayerController - how to tell what bitrate is playing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming

The HTTP Live Streaming format supports variable bitrates, which are described in the m3u8 file.

Is it possible to get the bitrate of the currently playing stream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't get that information from MPMoviePlayerController

To get the information you want, you could use AVPlayer and AVPlayerItems, which will then create AVAsset items that you can interrogate to discover their properties.

Once you have a AVPlayer, you can find the current AVPlayerItem using `currentItem`. From that, you can get the `asset` property.

A `AVAsset` has `AVAssetTrack`s and this has the `formatDescriptions` property. Somewhere in there you should find the bitrate.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will need to read up on AVPlayer... only used MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: @Malcolm Box: although trying very hard i am getting tracks array as empty array. could you please guide me?